# TypeError: generate() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

I'm using odoo 9 and i'm tring to generate label with the custom module "product_print_zpl_barcode " when i press on the button "Generate label " it shows this error any help please ??

product_print_zpl_barcode.py

```
def generate(self):
    assert self.barcode
    if len(self.barcode) != 13:
        raise UserError(_(
            "This wizard only supports EAN13 for the moment. Barcode '%s' "
            "has %d digits instead of 13") % (
            self.barcode,
            len(self.barcode)))
    if not self.copies:
        raise UserError(_("The number of copies cannot be 0"))
    if self.barcode_type in ('price', 'weight'):
        vals = self._prepare_price_weight_barcode_type()
    elif self.barcode_type == 'product':
        vals = self._prepare_product_barcode_type()
    else:
        raise UserError(_(
            "Barcode Type %s is not supported for the moment")
            % self.barcode_type)
    vals.update({
        'state': 'step2',
        'zpl_filename': 'barcode_%s.zpl' % vals['barcode'],
        })
    self.write(vals)
    action = self.env['ir.actions.act_window'].for_xml_id(
        'product_print_zpl_barcode',
        'product_print_zpl_barcode_action')
    action.update({
        'res_id': self.id,
        'context': self._context,
        'views': False})
    return action
```

product_print_zpl_barcode_view.xml (This is the action of the button "Generate label")

```
<record id="product_print_zpl_barcode_form" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">product_print_zpl_barcode.form</field>
<field name="model">product.print.zpl.barcode</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Generate and Print Product Barcode">
     ......
      <footer>
            <button name="generate" type="object" string="Generate Label" class="btn-primary" states="step1"/>
 <button special="cancel" string="Close" class="oe_link" states="step2"/>
        </footer>
    </form>
</field>
</record>
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\Projet_Odoo\odoo-9.0c-20170627\openerp\http.py", line 650, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
 File "D:\Projet_Odoo\odoo-9.0c-20170627\openerp\http.py", line 687, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "D:\Projet_Odoo\odoo-9.0c-20170627\openerp\http.py", line 323, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Projet_Odoo\odoo-9.0c-20170627\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Projet_Odoo\odoo-9.0c-20170627\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "D:\Projet_Odoo\odoo-9.0c-20170627\openerp\http.py", line 966, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "D:\Projet_Odoo\odoo-9.0c-20170627\openerp\http.py", line 516, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "D:\Projet_Odoo\odoo-9.0c-20170627\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 899, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "D:\Projet_Odoo\odoo-9.0c-20170627\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 887, in _call_kw
return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: generate() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)
```

Comment: The error means you are sending 5 arguments to `generate` function but the function only take 1. Can you show how you calling `generate` function? Or maybe just simple like this? `def generate(self, barcode, copies, barcode_type, writes, id)` ( or maybe include `_context` and `_prepare_price_weight_barcode_type` too)

Comment: What should i add in def generate () to correct this error ??

Comment: You need to add `@api.multi` decorator to your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the answer i used and it works

```
@api.multi
def generate(self):
    assert self.barcode
    if len(self.barcode) != 13:
        raise UserError(_(
            "This wizard only supports EAN13 for the moment. Barcode '%s' "
            "has %d digits instead of 13") % (
            self.barcode,
            len(self.barcode)))
    if not self.copies:
        raise UserError(_("The number of copies cannot be 0"))
    if self.barcode_type in ('price', 'weight'):
        vals = self._prepare_price_weight_barcode_type()
    elif self.barcode_type == 'product':
        vals = self._prepare_product_barcode_type()
    else:
        raise UserError(_(
            "Barcode Type %s is not supported for the moment")
            % self.barcode_type)
    vals.update({
        'state': 'step2',
        'zpl_filename': 'barcode_%s.zpl' % vals['barcode'],
        })
    self.write(vals)
    action = self.env['ir.actions.act_window'].for_xml_id(
        'product_print_zpl_barcode',
        'product_print_zpl_barcode_action')
    action.update({
        'res_id': self.id,
        'context': self._context,
        'views': False})
    return action
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states: you are calling the function with 5 arguments, it only takes 1: self.

Can you show the code that's calling your function?

Comment: i have mentionned the function in the question def generate(self): .....